# Balanced binary tree python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
# stack_depth is initialised to 0
def find_in_tree(node, find_condition, stack_depth):
    assert (stack_depth < max_stack_depth), 'Deeper than max depth'
    stack_depth += 1
    result = []
    if find_condition(node):
        result += [node]
    for child_node in node.children:
        result.extend(find_in_tree(child_node, find_condition, stack_depth))
    return result
```

I need help understanding this piece of code. The question i want to answer is

**The Python function above searches the contents of a balanced binary tree.
 If an upper limit of 1,000,000 nodes is assumed what should the max_stack_depth constant be set to?**

From what I understand, this is a trick question. If you think about it, stack_depth is incremented every time the find_in_tree() function is called in the recursion. And we are trying to find a particular node in the tree.So the worst case would be when we have to search through all the nodes in the tree before we find it. Hence, max_stack_depth should 1,000,000?

If you look at when **stack_depth** increments then it looks like we will increment every time we access a node. And in our case we are accessing every single node every time. Because there is no return condition when stops the algorithm when the correct node is found.

Can someone please try to explain me their thought process.

Comment: Your question seem to be about the binary tree data structure as a concept in CS rather than any specific programming challenge related to it. I'd say this question is off-topic for StackOverflow and should be asked on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why `1x2x4x...`? Shouldn't it be `1+2+4+...`? Certainly, there are not a million nodes in the first 7 layers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiplying the number of nodes on each layer, you have to add them. For example, the number of nodes in the first four layers is `1+2+4+8=15`, not `1*2*4*8=64`.

```
                #                      1
      #                   #          + 2
  #       #           #       #      + 4
#   #   #   #       #   #   #   #    + 8 = 15
```

In general, the number of nodes in the first `n` layers is `2**(n+1)-1`. You can use logarithms to get the correct power and get the floor of that number. If you want fewer that that number, you would also have to subtract one from the power.

```
>>> math.floor(math.log(1000000, 2))
19
>>> sum(2**i for i in range(1, 20))
1048574
```

Concerning your edit: Yes, `stack_depth` is incremented with each node, but you are incrementing a *local* variable. The increment will carry to the child nodes (passed as a parameter) but not to the siblings, i.e. all the nodes at level `n` will be called with `stack_depth == n-1` (assuming it started as `0` on the first level). Thus, `max_stack_depth` should be `19` (or `20` if it starts with `1`) to visit the ~1,000,000 nodes in the first 19 levels of the tree.

Comment: Maybe, im thinking whatever I initally thought is not correct. And this is more of a trick question. With the answer just being 1,000,000.

Comment: If you think about it, stack_depth is incremented every time the find_in_tree() function is called in the recursion. And we are trying to find a particular node in the tree.So the worst cast would be when we have to search through all the nodes in the tree before we find it. Hence, 1,000,000?

Comment: @NipoonPatel No, if the tree only contains 1000000 elements, or the algo should only visit 1000000 nodes, then those 1000000 nodes will all be in the first 19 levels of the tree. A depth of 1000000 would only make sene if the algorithm would visit only one "path" through the node (as a proper binary search would do, but your algo visits _all_ the child nodes)

Comment: Yes as you said "my algo visits all the child nodes" so if you look at when stack_depth increments then it looks like we will increment every time we access a node. And in our case we are accessing every single node. Because there is no return condition when stops the algorithm when the correct node is found. If you get what I mean.

Comment: So the value of max_stack_depth should be 1,000,000.

Comment: @NipoonPatel Yes, you are incrementing it with each node, but you are incrementing the _local_ variable. The increment will carry to the child nodes (passed as a parameter) but not to the siblings. That's why it's called `max_stack_depth` and not `max_nodes_visited`.